# Django Chart using Highcharts

Tags: python, django, highcharts

I am following the highchart demos but I am do not understand how they are importing using the following line:

```
from ..charts import Chart, PivotChart
```

Please tell me the meaning of the above line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is relative import

[PEP 0328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Answer (score 1):

These are **explicit relative imports** which started with Python 2.5 >. These explicit relative imports use leading dots to indicate the current and parent packages involved in the relative import.